# How can I cast an ObservableList to an ObservableSet

Tags: java, java-11, observablelist, javafx-11

I'm migrating an application from `Java 1.7` to `Java 11` which uses `JavaFX`.

During the migration I met a cast probleme where I have an `ObservableList` and I need an `ObservableSet`.

I tried to cast with `(ObservableSet<MyObject>) MyObservableList<MyObject>` but I have  :

> ERROR; UNCOUGHT Exception java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper cannot be cast to
>   class javafx.collections.ObservableSet
>   (com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper and
>   javafx.collections.ObservableSet are in module javafx.base of loader
>   'app') java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper cannot be cast to
>   class javafx.collections.ObservableSet
>   (com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper and
>   javafx.collections.ObservableSet are in module javafx.base of loader
>   'app')

Do you have an idea to cast/transform this Object properly ?
Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot cast it, the internal representation is different. You can initialize a new `ObservableSet` object and [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html?is-external=true#addAll-java.util.Collection-) your list, which takes any kind of collection.

Comment: Ho...
Thank you for that, I will do it so !